# Alternative key combination for jumping to the end of a line to enter a semicolon

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, phpstorm

Due to automatic code completion, I regularly find myself in between parentheses, having to get to the end of a line to add the inevitable semicolon.

Then I have to get my right hand up, move it to the right, hit <kbd>End</kbd>, and come back to the main part of the keyboard again to enter the semicolon.

I perceive this as disturbing to my flow of typing, especially when writing on a notebook, as then those moves of my hand are very inefficient.

Is there already a key combination for reaching the end of a line, or adding a semicolon, within the main keyboard area? Or is it possible to configure PhpStorm in those regards?

(I'm using PhpStorm, but I added the IntelliJ IDEA tag to this question as I guess they would be similar regarding those basic features.)

[image: photo of a keyboard with the letter and number keys, as well as immediately adjacent keys, highlighted]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can assign any keyboard shortcut to the **Move Caret to Line End** action in `Settings` | `Keymap`.

Comment: I like regex style movements so I remapped the bookmark shortcuts CTRL-^, CTRL-$.

Comment: I just was going through the same frustration as @Raffael, I  changed this keymap shortcut to `ctrl + '` - I removed the default shortcut (Other | Grid) in order to store this. Grid puts grids on images viewed in the editor. I don't open many images so it was an acceptable lose.

Comment: On a Mac you can use `crtl + a` to move to the line start and `ctrl + e` to move to line end. Just like the terminal :)

Comment: I too find the ctrl + ' useful. Just changed the keyboard shortcut on VS Code.

Go to keyboard shortcut (or press ctrl + K and ctrl + S) then search cursorEnd and right click the option 'Change Key Binding' then input your shortcut and hit Enter.

Answer (score 56):

More efficiently: invoke `Edit` | `Complete Current Statement` (<kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Enter</kbd>) to automatically insert semicolon at end of line and start new line.

Comment: This should be the actual correct answer to the question.

Comment: It would be really great if the cursor did not move. This is great already but it could be better.

Answer (score 4):

You need to try [touchcursor](http://touchcursor.sourceforge.net/). I just love it.