# Smart typing in Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using Intellij IDEA for about a year and I still wonder if there is some type of smart shortcut for this scenario:

```
new In|[ENTER]
new Integer(|)
new Integer(10|)
new Integer(10|)[RIGHT ARROW]
new Integer(10).| (any method name)
```

This may sounds silly, but I find myself using the right arrow too much during my work day, so I'm looking for a simple solution to skip this part when typing. Is there any smart shortcut in Intellij IDEA to start typing method name (with dot ahead) while the caret is still where the arguments are (inside parentheses)?

Comment: hmm, not sure, maybe Complete statement? http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/completing-statements.html Maybe it will help?

Comment: @morpheus05 I know this feature very well. In this case it will only add ';' at the end of the statement.

Comment: You could remap the *Move Caret to Line End* shortcut as [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7554772/1354590) suggests, although that won't get you the method `.` (dot)

Comment: @kuporific Thanks, I didn't think about this. I've assigned ALT+'.' and ALT+SHIFT+ENTER to this action. It's not perfect, but it's better than END or RIGHT ARROW keys. It would be perfect if the dot will be automatically added with ALT+'.'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your own macro and assign a Keymap to it like so*:

1. `Edit | Macros | Start Macro Recording`
2. Perform the sequence of steps, <kbd>⌘→</kbd> followed by <kbd>.</kbd>
3. `Edit | Macros | Stop Macro Recording`
4. Name the macro, e.g. "Go to line end and start method"
5. In `Settings`, search for the macro name (to make it easier to find), select in `Keymap | Macros`
   [image]
6. Right-click and select `Add Keyboard Shortcut`, assign the "First Stroke" to <kbd>⌃⇧.</kbd>, for example
7. `OK` all the dialogs and try it out!

* These are the steps on Mac, there might be slight differences for other OSs.